# Discord.js | How to set output random from given jsondata links?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create random gif giver when people execute command `!hp-random`. I made a jsonData const here:

```js
const jsonData = {
    "1":"https://media.giphy.com/media/12nfFCZA0vyrSw/giphy.gif",
    "2":"https://media.giphy.com/media/26BRzozg4TCBXv6QU/giphy.gif",
    "3":"https://media.giphy.com/media/PXvCWUnmqVdks/giphy.gif",
    "4":"https://media.giphy.com/media/7Yif3ae99ksCc/giphy.gif",
    "5":"https://media.giphy.com/media/R65bZxLDrX2Mw/giphy.gif",
    "6":"https://media.giphy.com/media/6jemHpKLDe27C/giphy.gif",
    "7":"https://media.giphy.com/media/LLxwPAjfpLak8/giphy.gif",
    "8":"https://media.giphy.com/media/oydIov5VxxXcG0mu1P/giphy.gif",
    "9":"https://media.giphy.com/media/S3F8kkGTHZ4Y/giphy.gif",
    "10":"https://media.giphy.com/media/RLo8seQ4drmAW02wSA/giphy.gif",
    }
```

right after that I put this:

```
const values = Object.values(jsonData)
const randomValue = values[parseInt(Math.random(values.length))]

module.exports = {
    name: 'hp-random',
    description: "Gives random gif in chat",
    execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
        console.log(randomValue);

        //message.channel.send(`${randomValue}`);
    }
}
```

My problem is that it only outputs the first 1 and not the other 9 outputs in `jsonData`: outputs only this>`"https://media.giphy.com/media/12nfFCZA0vyrSw/giphy.gif"`

Console: (me executing the command in discord chat btw)

```
    \Discord bot> node .
I'm working
https://media.giphy.com/media/12nfFCZA0vyrSw/giphy.gif
https://media.giphy.com/media/12nfFCZA0vyrSw/giphy.gif
https://media.giphy.com/media/12nfFCZA0vyrSw/giphy.gif
https://media.giphy.com/media/12nfFCZA0vyrSw/giphy.gif
https://media.giphy.com/media/12nfFCZA0vyrSw/giphy.gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to move `const randomValue = values[parseInt(Math.random(values.length))]` inside your execute method so you create a new random variable every time a message is coming in.

The other issue is your random function. [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) doesn't take any parameters, so you can't call `Math.random(values.length)` and expect to call it anything else than a number between 0 and 1. You need to multiply the random value by the length of the array instead:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'hp-random',
  description: 'Gives random gif in chat',
  execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
    const values = Object.values(jsonData);
    const randomValue = values[parseInt(Math.random() * values.length)];

    console.log(randomValue);

    // message.channel.send(randomValue);
  },
};
```

Comment: before i had it like this `const randomValue = values[parseInt(Math.random() * values.length)];` but it didn't work out side my execute function. So i learned something new thanks :)